# In the F test, is a two-sided test mainly used?

Tags: f-test

I have a question about the F test.

In R language, three parameters "two.side", "less" and "greater" can be specified as arguments of var.test (). However, I can not specify a one-sided test like "one.side".

Also, in Microsoft Excel, the F. TEST function was a two-sided test, and the analysis tool's F test was a one-sided test.

I have considered that the one-sided test is mainly used in the F test. Am I wrong?

Comment: @nekoneko your question is unclear. However in relation to the variance test in R, "less" and "greater" are the two possible one sided alternatives. If you don't specify *which*  one-tailed alternative you're interested in, *it isn't one-tailed*. Naturally there isn't a "one.sided" without specifying "less" or "greater", and as soon as you do specify which side, it's obviously one-sided. It's exactly the same with a one-sided  t-test in R. Take a look at [`?t.test`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/t.test.html).

Comment: @glen_b Yeah, that should have been clearer. I deleted it (for now).

Comment: Thank you @Glen_b. It seems that I was misunderstood. I do not want to test "greater" and "less". So I have to choose "two.sided". Thank you again.

Comment: Glen_b♦ I would like to make your comment the best answer, so can you answer me?